# how to divide a large Elm program into smaller components

Tags: elm

I'd like to separate the View and Update parts of a program into separate source files, but then, how do I share the Message and Subscriptions declarations ?

Comment: Some example code at https://github.com/sporto/elm-tutorial-app/tree/master/src, with corresponding tutorial at http://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/05-resources/01-intro.html.

Comment: I think the preferred way to componentize is to break into small widgets each with update and view kept together. Your question suggests you need to refactor, and your approach may not be the best

Answer (score 9):

Think twice before splitting your modules, premature code splitting might be harmful to your project.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/halfzebra/elm-examples/tree/master/examples/fractal-architecture) of the project structure I use in my Elm apps.

### Messages

[Html.App.map](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.1.0/Html-App#map) allows us to tag a message for child component, so we could pass it to `Components.Counter.Update.update` function, when keyboard subscription emits a message.

```
module App.View exposing (..)

import Html.App
import Html exposing (text, div, Html)
import App.Model exposing (Model)
import App.Messages exposing (..)
import Components.Counter.View


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ Html.App.map Counter (Components.Counter.View.view model.counter) ]
```

### Subscriptions

To tag a message from a subscription, we have to use [Platform.Sub.map](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Platform-Sub#map)

Please see an example of subscription passing in `src/App/Subscriptions.elm`

```
module App.Subscriptions exposing (..)

import App.Model exposing (Model)
import App.Messages exposing (..)
import Components.Counter.Subscriptions


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    let
        counterSub =
            Components.Counter.Subscriptions.subscriptions model.counter
    in
        Sub.batch [ Sub.map Counter counterSub ]
```

### File structure

```
Main.elm                 -- Entry point, where App is initialized
Utils.elm                -- Utilities
App/
    Messages.elm
    Model.elm
    Subscriptions.elm
    Update.elm
    View.elm
Components/
    StatefulComponent/
        Messages.elm
        Model.elm
        Subscriptions.elm
        Update.elm
        View.elm
    StatefulComponentWithCommands/
        Commands.elm     -- Functions, which return Cmd msg
        Messages.elm
        Model.elm
        Subscriptions.elm
        Update.elm
        View.elm
    StatelessComponent/
        View.elm
```

Answer (score 1):

An Elm program can be progressively split into several files as follows :

- extract message declarations and associated types into `Messages.elm`

  1. Add `import Messages exposing (..)` in `Main.elm`.
  2. Compile it and test.
- extract model declaration and initialisation into `Models.elm`.

  1. Add `import Messages exposing (..)` in `Models.elm`.
  2. Add `import Models exposing (..)` in `Main.elm`
  3. Compile it and test
- extract the `view` function into `View.elm`.

  1. Add `import Messages exposing (..)` in `View.elm`.
  2. Add `import Models exposing (..)` in `View.elm`
  3. Add `import View exposing (..)` in `Main.elm`
  4. Compile it and test

A the end, `Main.elm` still has the subscriptions and update parts.  They can be extracted similarly.

See example at [github.com/sporto/elm-tutorial-app/tree/master/src](http://github.com/sporto/elm-tutorial-app/tree/master/src), with corresponding tutorial at [elm-tutorial.org/en/05-resources/01-intro.html](http://elm-tutorial.org/en/05-resources/01-intro.html).