# How do I break up my Elm view code into separate files?

Tags: refactoring, elm

So far all of my view code is still in my main file, `Main.elm`. Within that file, it's relatively well-factored, with the different parts of the view broken down appropriately.

My question: I'd really like to break it out into separate files, e.g.:
- `Views/Header.elm`
- `Views/InfoPage.elm`
- `Views/Footer.elm`
- etc

But I'm really not clear on how to do this. Sure, I can make the different files and import/export the functions that I need. Not difficult with very simple views (e.g. a footer), but I quickly ran into problems with more complex `view`s <strike>most of which contain app logic, i.e. calls to the update function</strike>. Of course, if I then import the `Msg`s to my separate view files, then I get a circular dependency. Apologies if this is a naive question, but how do I solve this? I just want to be able have different page sections in different files, it's so much easier for me to navigate like that than perma-scrolling around.

I've googled around and read a few posts about refactoring Elm apps ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196666/how-to-divide-a-large-elm-program-into-smaller-components)), but nothing focused specifically on the view code. Can anyone give me some pointers? Is it not possible to break out view code without also factoring out the app logic that it uses? (And what if that app logic is used elsewhere too?) I'd really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Richard Feldman’s talk at Elm Europe 2017 https://youtu.be/DoA4Txr4GUs introduces some ways to make views reusable. Basically you can pass Msg to view functions so that they don’t need to import Msg in separate files.

Comment: Thanks @ShuheiKagawa. I actually have watched that talk, but still didn't really get it. I guess I will have to watch again. Wouldn't you still have to import `Msg` in the different files even just so the types are available?

Comment: No, you don’t need to import `Msg`. If you pass a message as a type parameter, which starts with a lowercase, then you can create a function that can work with any message type. For example, `myButton : msg -> Html msg` and `myButton msg = button [ onClick msg ] [ text "Hi" ]` can be used with any concrete msg type as `onClick` itself works with any msg type. And you can use it in a separate file like `myButton OneOfYourMsgConstructor`.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your dependencies as follows:

```
      Model.elm (includes Model and Msg)
          ^        ^
          |        |
      View.elm  Update.elm
          ^        ^
          |        |
           Main.elm
```

You say that you "ran into problems with more complex views, most of which contain app logic, i.e. calls to the update function." But views should not contain app logic and do not call the update function. Views only need to declare what `Msg` constructor to use to handle various events, so view and update are completely decoupled.

Comment: Hi @la-yumba, and thanks. I did not use the right terminology when I wrote my post - my view code didn't (and doesn't) contain calls to `update`, but instead uses `Msg`s, as you wrote. I ended up arranging it a bit similar to what you show above, although my `Main.elm` also imports `Model` and currently my `Msg` union type is living in `Update.elm`.